# Can gems meant to be crafted from something like star dust be named as "Skyrocks"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

We have game what uses gems crafted from star dust as points. Can that gems be named as "Skyrocks"? Is this name clear enough? Or what can be better name?

[image: It looks like this]

[image: Or this]

Comment: Question was put on hold as primarily opinion-based, but I'm asking not about opinions, but about how it's correctly from view of native skeaker (because I'm not one). Excuse me If I not correctly understand rules of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a game, you can call an object any thing you want. With that being said, skyrocks does seem a little odd.  Why not star rocks, star gems, or star fire? Or maybe all three depending on the size crafted.